# iOS7 Loading three images in one cell on iPad is lagy, scrolling freez

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I have big problem with my iPad application which I am working on. I will explain you what is a problem.

I have list of products. I have table view to show that products. I try to load 3 images (products) in one cell in landscape mode and 2 in portrait mode. For that I use this code in my controller class

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
  [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

  dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND,  0ul);
  dispatch_async(queue, ^{

    for(int i = 0; i < self.cols; i++){
      int index = (indexPath.row * self.cols) + i;

      if([self.productList count] > 0 && index < [self.productList count]){
        Product *tmpProduct = nil;
        if([self.productList isKindOfClass:[NSMutableSet class]]){
          tmpProduct = (Product *)[[NSArray arrayWithArray:[((NSSet *)self.productList) allObjects]]  objectAtIndex:index];
        }else{
          tmpProduct = (Product *)[((NSArray *)self.productList) objectAtIndex:index];
        }

        int x = i * self.itemWidth + (50 * (i + 1));
        int y = 0;
        int imageWidth = self.itemWidth;
        int imageHeight = self.itemHeight - 45;

        UIView *awesomeView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, imageWidth, self.itemHeight)];
        awesomeView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        awesomeView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        awesomeView.tag = 700;

        UIImage *image;
        if([tmpProduct getImageFilePath]){
          image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[tmpProduct getImageFilePath]];
        }else{
          image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"no-image.png"];
        }
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

          UIImageView *productImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: image];
          CGRect frameRect = productImage.frame;
          frameRect.size.width = imageWidth;
          frameRect.size.height = imageHeight;
          productImage.frame = frameRect;
          productImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
          productImage.tag = index;
          productImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
          productImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

          [awesomeView addSubview:productImage];
          [cell.contentView addSubview:awesomeView];
          [cell setNeedsLayout];
        });

      }
    }
  });
  return cell;
}
```

You can see that when cell want to show and "cellForRowAtIndexPath" method is called I initiate background queue. Start "for" for 3 or 2 images in one cell. Get product for that cell based on row. Calculating image width and height and position. Initiate one helper view. Than load image. If image exists in product object I load product image if not I loaddefault image (no-image). Place that image view in my helper view. After that I load my helper view to cell in main queue. (I use that helper view "awesomeView" because I have more thing to display, some labels, i removed that to simplified this question).

Here is youtube video which I have recorded to see which problem i have. You can see that when I scroll up or down it is very lagy. It freeze for part of second every time when script load next cell. YOUTUBE Video: http://youtu.be/hE3KI0SVrPk

Can some one help me I do not know where I am wrong.

I tried couple of combinations with queues and also I tried without queues and result is almost the same.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: do you know about UITableView cell reuse? using dequeueCellWithReuseIdentifier instead of calling alloc init for every row will definitely help your performance. also, what is the motivation behind dispatch_async? the code you have async'd is not nearly intensive enough to warrant this.

Comment: When I use dequeueCellWithReuseIdentifier my cells got duplicated views. And in that case I need to empty cell when I inserting new images. Is this faster or just to allocate cell every time?

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to do this is as follows:

- create some mutable collection to hold images
- when you find you need an image, and its not in the collection, do (somewhat) as you are doing - get the image in the background
- keep an index or some id of what you are currently fetching, so you don't do it more than once.
- when you get the image, then dispatch_async to a method in your view controller
- the receiving method receives the image, and examines all the visible cells in the table (there's a method for that), to see if the image applies to any of them. If so it updates that cell. If not it puts the image into the mutable collection.

In my case I had a known productID I could use as a key to use with a mutable dictionary. I would when first fetching an image add an entry of `[NSNull null]` for the object of the key - that made it easy to test for whether or not I already was fetching the image. Once I got the image, the image replaced the nsnull placeholder.

Comment: "create some mutable collection to hold images", I wouldn't do that because if he has lots of images in memory it will cause crashes. it would be better to use AFNetworking or some library with caching to automatically handle this for you.

Comment: That is reason why I use TableCell to load only visible images and avoid load all images. Because I have lot of images on one view. Maybe I can load 3-4 rows (cells) in advanced and store to mutable collection and when cell come just to show. But I am not sure will that work without lags.

Comment: You are not doing it that way - this is definitely the wrong way "dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue()" - sync! No wonder your problems. Also by this time the cell may have been recycled to some other row in your table.

Comment: @OliverAtkinson, well it was a start. What I did was use a NSCache - if the system has the memory fine, if not, then it can free the cache and you have to fetch again. But at this point there is so much wrong with the approach it needs to get stabilized into something workable first.

Comment: @OliverAtkinson UIImage already leverages an image cache, managed by the system. AFN wont't do better. David's solution is easy to accomplish - and viable. There are more sophisticated solutions, but these would require *much more* effort. I haven't seen a library yet which would provide such features, though.

Comment: I see that this problem is not easy to solve :) My question for now is, what causing that lagging and freezing? Which line of code? Is that UIImageView *productImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: image]; or any other line? Can I load in mutable collection views including images for next 3 cells and previous 3 cells in background queue and just to display in cell when cell want to show without lagging? Thank you very very much for your help!

Comment: No, the problem is easy to solve - do as I said in my answer. Your use of dispatch_sync is the worst offender. However, you may be setting an image on a recycled cell. Its not like you have one line to fix, its that your architecture here is flawed and you need to fix that ASAP.

Comment: This type of question has been asked her many times, and I have no doubt you can find some. Just getting the code won't be of great help if you could not code it yourself, since you would never be able to debug something you don't understand. My suggestion is to not try and do it all at once. So at first, get the part of identifying a missing image, retrieving it in the background, the posting it to the main queue. When you get that working, you will find its pretty easy to apply the image if a visible cell uses that image. If you do it a step at a time, it will all fall into place.